# Check declaration of XML file in Python

Tags: xml, python-3.x, heading

How can i check, if given XML file contains its declaration (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`) using `xml.etree.ElementTree` library ?
Thank you!

Comment: Could you not check that without `xml.etree.ElementTree` ? Simply by reading and comparing the first line ?

Comment: I could ofc., but it looks to me, that it is "ugly way" to do that. I would also need to read the file two times - as string & as XMLfile - so I wanted to know, if there is a "nice and clean way" to do this. If not, I will be pushed to compare it as two strings anyway.